# How can I make a matrix of same strings in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, matrix

[Tuna ,Tuna;Tuna ,Tuna]

I want to make this kind of matrix but 5x5 version of it. Is there any function to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is to use [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) to do this for you.

```
tuna = cell(5);
[tuna{:}] = deal('Tuna');

    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'
    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'
    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'
    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'
    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'    'Tuna'
```

Or, as [suggested by @Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290694/how-can-i-make-a-matrix-of-same-strings-in-matlab/36291108?noredirect=1#comment60208318_36291108):

```
tuna = cell(5);
tuna(:) = {'Tuna'};
```

If you *don't* want a cell array and simply a character array you can use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) on the string itself.

```
repmat('Tuna', 5)

    TunaTunaTunaTunaTuna
    TunaTunaTunaTunaTuna
    TunaTunaTunaTunaTuna
    TunaTunaTunaTunaTuna
    TunaTunaTunaTunaTuna
```

Comment: also: `C = cell(5); C(:) = {'Tuna'}`

Comment: @Amro doh. I always forget that!

Answer (score 2):

```
A{1} = 'Tuna'; 
B = repmat(A, 5);
```

To clarify, `A{1} = 'Tuna'` creates a single cell with a string. If you were to use `A = 'Tuna'`, you would be creating a vector of characters. Performing repmat on the vector of characters in this way would actually create a 5x20 character array.

Comment: or `repmat({'Tuna'}, 5)`